# How to access varibales defined in a controller by a viewer in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class TestController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
            var xmDTO = XFacade.XList();

        return View(xmDTO );
    }}
```

My controller is look like that and I want to access the list from my viewer 
 How to do that ?
I wont come when I use xmDTO in a loop

Comment: you should strongly type your view

Comment: um using Razor so it wont help and not MVC4 style

Comment: passing data in Model or viewbag & accessing it in view will be good approach

Comment: how to pass Data in a Model  or a View Bag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ViewBag will be good approach

Controller class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.country = new List<string>()
            {
                "USA",
                "INDIA",
                "UK"
            };
            return View();
        }

    }

}
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of string value";
}


<h2>Country List</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (string  country in ViewBag .country)
    {
        <li>@country</li>
    }
```

Comment: @MDDDC whats your approach?

Comment: Yes it is, you should avoid to use ViewBag in your app !What is benefit of ViewBag in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you strongly type your view?

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var xmDTO = XFacade.XList();

        return View(xmDTO );
    }
}
```

in your view

```
@model XList<type>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of string value";
}


@foreach (var item in country in Model)
{
    //use properties in item
}
```